# Dynamic Modal Issue JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am building a page with multiple divs that contain a unique image and title. There is a button in each div and when I click the button, it is supposed to grab the unique image and unique title and display it in the modal. My problem is it is grabbing all of the texts from every div and only showing the image from the first div.
HTML:

```
<div class="col2">
    <div class="crop">
        <img class="product-image" src="products/IMG_0002.jpg" alt="Generic placeholder image" id="image">
    </div>
    <div class="text-container">
        <a class="product-title" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" href='#' id="cap"> Title </a>
    </div>
    <p><a class="btn btn-secondary" role="button" id="button1" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">View details &raquo;</a></p>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
            var image = $('.crop img').attr('src');
            var caption = $('.text-container a').text();
            $(".img-responsive").attr("src", image);
             $(".caption").text(caption);
        });
});
```

modal html:

```
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <div class="pull-left">
                        <p class="caption">""</p>
                    </div>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" title="Close"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="" />
                    <!--end modal-body-->
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                </div>
                <div class="pull-left">
                    <button class="btn-sm close" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <!--end modal-footer-->
                </div>
                <!--end modal-content-->
            </div>
            <!--end modal-dialoge-->
        </div>
        <!--end myModal-->>
    </div>
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to add context to your selectors. Without context, you are selecting every element that matches a given selector.

Here's a revision of your code and a brief explanation below:

```
$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
    var sourceTarget = $(e.relatedTarget).closest('.col2')[0]
    var image = $('img.product-image', sourceTarget).attr('src');
    var caption = $('.product-title', sourceTarget).text();
    $('.img-responsive', this).attr('src', image);
    $('.caption', this).text(caption);
});
```

`e.relatedTarget` is the trigger element passed on by the event object which gives you direct access to the button that's just been clicked.

Using this related target we are able to traverse up the tree to find `.col2`, the containment, which we will refer to as `sourceTarget`. Now we are able to fetch any element contained within this `sourceTarget` element.

`this` is simply the element context in which the modal plugin is executed on (in this case `#myModal`).

> Since you have multiple `<div />` elements containing unique data I
>   would avoid using the same `id` attribute for the images and text.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am getting empty modals :(. I have not much experience with JQuery by the way.

Comment: Just letting you know, The title in the div also triggers the modal when clicked, and for that it is displaying the title correctly in the modal but not the image. When the button is clicked, the modal is empty.

Comment: I realised I put `.parent()` when the button is actually in a `<p />` so I've tweaked the code which uses `.closest()` to find the nearest container. This also helps with the trigger being placed on other elements within the column.